# Why are H1 tags excluded from NuxtJS's Content module's TOC list?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, markdown, nuxt-content

I am in the process of importing a lot of markdown content which all use a fair amount of H1 (#) tags. While creating a TOC component, I noticed that H1 tags are excluded from the @Nuxt/Content's conveniently provided TOC array.

This is proving to be quite a headache for me, and I would rather not write a script to change hundreds of MD files to modify each heading to be one level deeper, although it is an option.

Things I have tried:

```
    mounted() {
        this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                const id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    this.currentlyActiveToc = id;
                }
            });
        }, this.observerOptions);

        // Including h1 explicitly to the function
        document.querySelectorAll('.nuxt-content h1[id], .nuxt-content h2[id], .nuxt-content h3[id]').forEach((section) => {
            this.observer.observe(section);
        });
    },
```

Modifying `content/parsers/markdown/index.js` `generateToc` function to include h1 in `const depth`

```
  generateToc (body) {
    const { tocTags } = this.options

    const children = this.flattenNode(body, 2)

    return children.filter(node => tocTags.includes(node.tag)).map((node) => {
      const id = node.props.id

      const depth = ({
        h1: 2,
        h2: 3,
        h3: 4,
        h4: 5,
        b5: 6
      })[node.tag]

      const text = this.flattenNodeText(node)

      return {
        id,
        depth,
        text
      }
    })
  }
```

In Nuxt/Vue the document object is still not registering h1 tags to be included in the TOC. Does anyone have a workaround or an idea of how to include them?

Lastly -- are using H1 / `#` tags to separate major sections in markdown not considered good practice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I imagine because the page is supposed to have a single H1 designating the title of the document, and then H2s (and lower) designating the sub-sections of that document, which are collated in the document’s table of contents.

Comment: @MartinBean That's what I suspected, but as we were using YAML blocks for document titles we didn't think that it would be a big problem down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking in the wrong place.

I managed to add H1 tags to the TOC list by changing the `content/lib/utils.js` file.

```
  const { tocDepth } = markdown
  const tocTags = []

  if (tocDepth < 1) {
    logger.info(`content.markdown.tocDepth is set as ${tocDepth}. Table of contents of markdown files will be empty.`)
    return tocTags
  }

  if (tocDepth > 6) {
    logger.info(`content.markdown.tocDepth is set as ${tocDepth}. Table of contents of markdown files will include all the headings.`)
  }


  // CHANGE LINE BELOW FROM i=2 to i=1

  for (let i = 1; i <= tocDepth; i++) {
    tocTags.push(`h${i}`)
  }

  return tocTags
}
```

Couldn't find anything on the web that related to this question, so hope this helps someone!